# WPF toolkit for tile listview

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I need to create tiles of well formatted buttons, something like the Windows 8 start page. Is there any toolkit available for a custom ListView which may support tile view or grid view, with some formatting and may be some animation options.

I tried creating my own custom listview but it seemed to be a complicated task.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I am not aware of a nice free tile control. [DevExpress](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVmF9_BGHoM) has a nice looking commercial version.

If you'd specify your exact requirements (i.e. what properties do you need configurable, what kind of animation,...) and I find the time, I would give it a whirl though.

EDIT: I've created an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel. Using the MVVM pattern, expanding the controls to your needs and your data objects should not be too difficult. Rather hard to do is the DragDrop behavior part -  there certainly is still some room for improvement. I didn't include the images.

[image]

TileControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.TileControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Behavior"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TileTypeToColorConverter x:Key="TileTypeToColorConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Themes/background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Border x:Name="darkenBorder" Background="Black" Opacity="0.6" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" Background="Transparent" Margin="5">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <beh:ItemsControlDragDropBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:TileModel">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Background="{Binding TileType, Converter={StaticResource TileTypeToColorConverter}}"
                               Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Width="120" Height="110" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"  >
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Padding="5" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="tileBackground" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Opacity="0.9" />
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="50"  />
                                        <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,10" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                        <Button.Resources>
                            <ElasticEase x:Key="easeOutBounce" EasingMode="EaseOut" Springiness="6" Oscillations="4" />
                        </Button.Resources>
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:00.05" AutoReverse="True">
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="0.1" To="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easeOutBounce}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" From="0.1" To="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easeOutBounce}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.1" To="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easeOutBounce}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel, TileModel, TileType, ActionCommand:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TileModel> _tiles;
        public ObservableCollection<TileModel> Tiles { get { return _tiles; } set { _tiles = value; OnPropertyChanged("Tiles"); } }

        public ViewModel()
        {

           Tiles= new ObservableCollection<TileModel>()
            {
                new TileModel() { Text = "Facebook", Image = Properties.Resources.Facebook.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Website },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Skype", Image = Properties.Resources.Skype.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Application },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Ask.com", Image = Properties.Resources.AskCom.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Website  },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Amazon", Image = Properties.Resources.Amazon.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Website },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Evernote", Image = Properties.Resources.Evernote.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Application },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Twitter", Image = Properties.Resources.Twitter.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Website },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Internet Explorer",  Image = Properties.Resources.InterneExplorer.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Browser },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Android", Image = Properties.Resources.Android.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Application },
                new TileModel() { Text = "Winamp", Image = Properties.Resources.Winamp.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Application },
                new TileModel() { Text = "YouTube", Image = Properties.Resources.YouTube.ToBitmapImage(), TileType = TileType.Website },
            };
        }

    }


    public class TileModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _text;
        public string Text { get { return _text; } set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); } }

        private BitmapSource _image;
        public BitmapSource Image { get { return _image; } set { _image = value; OnPropertyChanged("Image"); } }

        private TileType _tileType;
        public TileType TileType { get { return _tileType; } set { _tileType = value; OnPropertyChanged("TileType"); } }

        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; private set; }

        public TileModel()
        {
            ClickCommand = new ActionCommand(Click);
        }

        private void Click()
        {
            // execute appropriate action
        }

    }

    public enum TileType
    {
        Browser,
        Website,
        Application
    }

    public class ActionCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private Action _action;

        public ActionCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_action != null)
                _action();
        }
    }
}
```

ItemsControlDragDropBehavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1.Behavior
{
    public class ItemsControlDragDropBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
    {
        private bool _isMouseDown;
        private bool _isDragging;
        private Point _dragStartPosition;
        private UIElement _dragItem;
        private UIElement _dragContainer;
        private IDataObject _dataObject;
        private int _currentDropIndex;
        private Point _lastCheckPoint;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.AllowDrop = true;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewDragOver += AssociatedObject_PreviewDragOver;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewDrop += AssociatedObject_PreviewDrop;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;

            base.OnAttached();
        }

        void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemsControl itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;
            Point p = e.GetPosition(itemsControl);

            object data = itemsControl.GetDataObjectFromPoint(p);
            _dataObject = data != null ? new DataObject(data.GetType(), data) : null;

            _dragContainer = itemsControl.GetItemContainerFromPoint(p);
            if (_dragContainer != null)
                _dragItem = GetItemFromContainer(_dragContainer);

            if (data != null)
            {
                _isMouseDown = true;
                _dragStartPosition = p;
            }
        }

        void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isMouseDown)
            {
                ItemsControl itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;
                Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(itemsControl);
                if ((_isDragging == false) && (Math.Abs(currentPosition.X - _dragStartPosition.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) ||
                    (Math.Abs(currentPosition.Y - _dragStartPosition.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
                {
                    DragStarted(e.GetPosition(itemsControl));
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        void AssociatedObject_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDropIndex(e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject));
        }

        void AssociatedObject_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDropIndex(e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject));
        }

        void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;
        }

        private void DragStarted(Point p)
        {
            if (!_isDragging)
            {
                _isDragging = true;

                if (_dragContainer != null)
                    _dragContainer.Opacity = 0.3;

                _currentDropIndex = FindDropIndex(p);

                DragDropEffects e = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.AssociatedObject, _dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);

                ResetState();
            }
        }

        private void ResetState()
        {
            if (_dragContainer != null)
                _dragContainer.Opacity = 1.0;

            _isMouseDown = false;
            _isDragging = false;
            _dataObject = null;
            _dragItem = null;
            _dragContainer = null;
            _currentDropIndex = -1;
        }

        private void UpdateDropIndex(Point p)
        {
            if ((_lastCheckPoint - p).Length > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) // prevent too frequent call
            {
                int dropIndex = FindDropIndex(p);
                if (dropIndex != _currentDropIndex && dropIndex > -1)
                {
                    this.AssociatedObject.RemoveItem(_dataObject);
                    this.AssociatedObject.AddItem(_dataObject, dropIndex);
                    _currentDropIndex = dropIndex;
                }
                _lastCheckPoint = p;
            }
        }

        private int FindDropIndex(Point p)
        {
            ItemsControl itemsControl = this.AssociatedObject;
            UIElement dropTargetContainer = null;

            dropTargetContainer = itemsControl.GetItemContainerFromPoint(p);

            int index = -1;
            if (dropTargetContainer != null)
            {
                index = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dropTargetContainer);

                if (!IsPointInTopHalf(p))
                    index = index++; // in second half of item, add after
            }
            else if (IsPointAfterAllItems(itemsControl, p))
            {
                // still within itemscontrol, but after all items
                index = itemsControl.Items.Count - 1;
            }

            return index;
        }

        public bool IsPointInTopHalf(Point p)
        {
            ItemsControl itemsControl = this.AssociatedObject;

            bool isInTopHalf = false;

            UIElement selectedItemContainer = itemsControl.GetItemContainerFromPoint(p);
            Point relativePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(selectedItemContainer);

            if (IsItemControlOrientationHorizontal())
                isInTopHalf = relativePosition.X < ((FrameworkElement)selectedItemContainer).ActualWidth / 2;
            else
                isInTopHalf = relativePosition.Y < ((FrameworkElement)selectedItemContainer).ActualHeight / 2;

            return isInTopHalf;
        }

        private bool IsItemControlOrientationHorizontal()
        {
            bool isHorizontal = false;
            Panel panel = GetItemsPanel();
            if (panel is WrapPanel)
                isHorizontal = ((WrapPanel)panel).Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal;
            else if (panel is StackPanel)
                isHorizontal = ((StackPanel)panel).Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal;

            return isHorizontal;
        }

        private UIElement GetItemFromContainer(UIElement container)
        {
            UIElement item = null;
            if (container != null)
                item = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0) as UIElement;
            return item;
        }

        private Panel GetItemsPanel()
        {
            ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter = GetVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(this.AssociatedObject);
            Panel itemsPanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsPresenter, 0) as Panel;
            return itemsPanel;
        }

        private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);

            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }

        /// still needs some work
        private static bool IsPointAfterAllItems(ItemsControl itemsControl, Point point)
        {
            bool isAfter = false;

            UIElement target = itemsControl.GetLastItemContainer();
            Point targetPos = target.TransformToAncestor(itemsControl).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            Point relativeToTarget = new Point(point.X - targetPos.X, point.Y - targetPos.Y);

            if (relativeToTarget.X >= 0 && relativeToTarget.Y >= 0)
            {
                var bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
                isAfter = !bounds.Contains(relativeToTarget);
            }
            return isAfter;
        }
    }

    public static class ItemsControlExtensions
    {
        public static object GetDataObjectFromPoint(this ItemsControl itemsControl, Point p)
        {
            UIElement element = itemsControl.InputHitTest(p) as UIElement;

            while (element != null)
            {
                if (element == itemsControl)
                    return null;

                object data = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
                if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                    return data;
                else
                    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static UIElement GetItemContainerFromPoint(this ItemsControl itemsControl, Point p)
        {
            UIElement element = itemsControl.InputHitTest(p) as UIElement;

            while (element != null)
            {
                object data = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);

                if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                    return element;
                else
                    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
            }

            return element;
        }

        public static UIElement GetLastItemContainer(this ItemsControl itemsControl)
        {
            UIElement container = null;
            if (itemsControl.HasItems)
                container = itemsControl.GetItemContainerAtIndex(itemsControl.Items.Count - 1);

            return container;
        }

        public static UIElement GetItemContainerAtIndex(this ItemsControl itemsControl, int index)
        {
            UIElement container = null;

            if (itemsControl != null && itemsControl.Items.Count > index && itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                container = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as UIElement;
            else
                container = itemsControl;

            return container;
        }

        public static void AddItem(this ItemsControl itemsControl, IDataObject item, int insertIndex)
        {
            if (itemsControl.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                foreach (string format in item.GetFormats())
                {
                    object data = item.GetData(format);
                    IList iList = itemsControl.ItemsSource as IList;
                    if (iList != null)
                        iList.Insert(insertIndex, data);
                    else
                    {
                        Type type = itemsControl.ItemsSource.GetType();
                        Type genericList = type.GetInterface("IList`1");
                        if (genericList != null)
                            type.GetMethod("Insert").Invoke(itemsControl.ItemsSource, new object[] { insertIndex, data });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                itemsControl.Items.Insert(insertIndex, item);
        }

        public static void RemoveItem(this ItemsControl itemsControl, IDataObject itemToRemove)
        {
            if (itemToRemove != null)
            {
                foreach (string format in itemToRemove.GetFormats())
                {
                    object data = itemToRemove.GetData(format);
                    int index = itemsControl.Items.IndexOf(data);
                    if (index > -1)
                        itemsControl.RemoveItemAt(index);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveItemAt(this ItemsControl itemsControl, int removeIndex)
        {
            if (removeIndex != -1 && removeIndex < itemsControl.Items.Count)
            {
                if (itemsControl.ItemsSource != null)
                {
                    IList iList = itemsControl.ItemsSource as IList;
                    if (iList != null)
                    {
                        iList.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Type type = itemsControl.ItemsSource.GetType();
                        Type genericList = type.GetInterface("IList`1");
                        if (genericList != null)
                            type.GetMethod("RemoveAt").Invoke(itemsControl.ItemsSource, new object[] { removeIndex });
                    }
                }
                else
                    itemsControl.Items.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TileTypeToColorConverter:

```
public class TileTypeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
        TileType type = (TileType)value;
        switch (type)
        {
            case TileType.Browser: brush.Color = Colors.Maroon; break;
            case TileType.Application: brush.Color = Colors.DodgerBlue; break;
            case TileType.Website: brush.Color = Colors.DarkGoldenrod; break;
        }
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: animation-> may be list items appearing one by one after some delay, drag and drop feature for tile items, capability to add images or checkboxes.

Comment: tiles always the same size, same margin? what of the tiles do you need configurable (e.g. color, text, icon, type: checkbox/normal button, ...)? how should the control behave when it is resized?

Comment: yeah same size, same margin and configurable-> everything (background image,text, icon), when resized, it should accomodate space for other tile items and the other tile items should move smoothly when resized.

Comment: the problem with this is that it has bad performance. (atom cpu)

Comment: @adabyron I've implemented a similar solution.  Do you have any ideas to persist the index of the model? Use App Settings?  Config file?  Who is responsible for persisting the index?  When is it persisted?

Comment: @JesseSeger: Sorry for the late reply, I was gone for a year.
The answer to your questions strongly depends on your application. Most likely, you will want to use Isolated Storage. The moment you persist it is when you exit the application, so find an event that suits you, most likely `MainWindow_OnClosing` or `Application_Exit`. All you need to do is getting the `DataContext`, and then save the sequence of the tile collection - it's not even necessary to keep an index property directly on the `TileModel`.

Comment: @Parhs: Performance problems here will almost certainly be an effect of the animations used. Scale them down to your needs.

Comment: @MikeFuchs: I really liked your solution. Could you explain why you use PreviewMouse events instead of PreviewDrag events?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Item Control,
i). In Item Panel just give the number of rows and columns you want
ii). If button you want here are to be generated dynamically just assign the list of Buttons to it.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstButtons"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Columns="4"
                   Rows="4" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button  Click="CLICK_EVENT_HERE"
               Style="Use metro Button Style here" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```