# C# WPF dynamically create a GUI element for each object in list

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, tiles

I have a list of objects (same class). Each of these objects has couple of properties. I would like to build a GUI that would show a "tile" for each of these objects and in this "tile" the property values of this object would be displayed. The image bellow illustrates the idea.

[image]

By pressing on the + tile it would be possible to add new object (would bring up the dialogue). The object tiles would wrap to the next line allowing X tiles per line.

What would be your suggestions to do this in a civilized manner to be able to automatically add/remove tiles as an object in the list is created/deleted? Maybe someone knows some examples?

Currently I'm quite blank on how to achieve this.

Comment: Put your items in an `ObservableCollection` and use [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a UI for your objects.

Comment: They are already in ObservableCollection :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using some sort of `ItemsControl` with a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I would review the follow tutorial on how to do that: http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html

---

As Matt Burland stated, you will need to put your objects into a [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for them to appear "dynamically".

Comment: And a command (RelayCommand if you use MVVMLight) for your "+" button in order to bring up the "Create New" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this post -

[WPF toolkit for tile listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652597/wpf-toolkit-for-tile-listview)

it outlines using a ItemsControl with wrap panel create a tile effect.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a ListBox, bind ItemsSource property to your List.
2) Insert whatever kind of object you like in that list.
3) Create DataTemplate for each kind of object to display